# Search a keyword from the selected table in Combo

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a combobox, which contains table names and a text field for the keyword. What I'm trying to do is to search the keyword from selected table, in the combobox.

My Java classes are mapped to the tables by @Table annotation. 
I need an idea for the model to design this kind of application. I don't want to generate native sql queries,

thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem using Java Reflections.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hibernate Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) or [JPA2 Criteria Queries](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/jpa_2_criteria.html). Then then only thing you need to do is, mapping the Table Name to an Class, afterwards you can use it in your queries.